# Split value of a row with equal values based on the unique entry

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have a dataframe which looks like this:

```
Name  T1  T2  alpha
A     10  3   30
A     11  5   Nan
A     13  5   Nan
B     5   2   7
B     3   1   Nan
```

However need to divide the `alpha` column in equal parts to replace `Nan` values for each unique names in `Name` column like this: eg `30` for `A` becomes `10` each for corresponding row where `A` is present

```
Name  T1  T2  alpha
A     10  3   10
A     11  5   10
A     13  5   10
B     5   2   3.5
B     3   1   3.5
```

I tried using `explode` but it is not working as I want it to look like, any idea here would help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `groupby` and `transform`

```
df['alpha'] = pd.to_numeric(df['alpha'],errors = 'coerce').fillna(0).groupby(df['Name']).transform('mean')
df
Out[50]: 
  Name  T1  T2  alpha
0    A  10   3   10.0
1    A  11   5   10.0
2    A  13   5   10.0
3    B   5   2    3.5
4    B   3   1    3.5
```

Answer (score 0):

This'll get the job done:

```py
df['alpha'] = (df['alpha'] / df['T2']).ffill()
```

Output:

```
  Name  T1  T2  alpha
0    A  10   3   10.0
1    A  11   5   10.0
2    A  13   5   10.0
3    B   5   2    3.5
4    B   3   1    3.5
```

Comment: are you sure about the solution. Nowhere it takes the 'Name' as the key to fill in empty rows